# What does really mean in the angle bisector containing the origin?

Tags: coordinate-systems

" ...... algorithm may be used to find the bisector of the angle containing the origin....."
what I meant is that there are two lines. When they meet, they form an acute angle ( say K) and also an angle of ( π - k) . The angular region which contains the origin is desired. Even though, I could use the formula to solve simple problems using the algorithm, but I can't get a very intuitive image of what really is happening in the algorithm.
Providing a physical and intuitive picture so that one ( atleast I) can understand it completely would be of great help.

Comment: Are you attempting to understand what someone wrote, looking for suggestions for better phrasing in something you're writing, or wanting to solve some problem which involves this bisector?

Comment: the statement under quote is given in my textbook which I used to indicate the topic. What I want is the real and intuitive concept for how really thee algorithm of bisector containing the origin works m